# How can I render the previous page with partial views in it showing me exactly what they showed me prior to rederecting to that prev page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I render the previous page with partial views in it showing me exactly what they showed me prior to redirecting to that prev page in ASP.NET MVC?

So, I have a start page, then user doing some actions, depending on them some partial view are rendering (use $.ajax method for that purpose), then user goes to another page and go back to previous one. As a result, he sees the prev page but only as it initially was without partial views' content.

Comment: with a lot of work.  you will need to save all of the data that is needed to recreate the page and if the partials are loaded via click you will need to go through those and reclick them on page load.  Unfortunately there isn't a quick fix on this one

Answer (score 0):

Is the "other page" part of your MVC website? If so, you can call the second page using AJAX and get it's partial HTML. Then, you can pop-up a Bootstrap modal window, which contains that partial HTML. The user will see her previous values on the initial page because they never navigated away of the initial page.

The Bootstrap guide is here:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

You put the HTML returned by your ActionResult in the body of the modal like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/MyController/_MyPartial",
    cache: false,
    traditional: true
}).done(function (htmlFromPartial) {
    $('.modal-body').html(htmlFromPartial);
}).fail(function () {
    alert('Cannot get my partial HTML!');
});
```

Your `ActionResult _MyPartial()` must return `PartialView()` as you usually would.
It works for me in many occasions but ht code above is untested.

Comment: While this is not an answer om my question, but this is a good way to escape navigating to prev page. And I guess it's much easier to do it that way than reload all partials like Matt Bodily said. I'll certainly try this one.